# How to get parent node's ID as a parameter?

Tags: graphql

The requirement is:

1. Get a list of movies that are playing on a specific date within X radius
2. For each movie get venues that are playing that movie (in order of a distance)
3. For each venue, get events that are playing movie on that date

The current schema is:

```
type Query {
  movies (
    first: Int
    after: String
    coordinates: CoordinatesInput!
    date: String
  ): MovieConnection!  
}

type Movie implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  venues (
    first: Int
    after: String
    movieId: ID!
    coordinates: CoordinatesInput!
    date: String!
  ): VenueConnection!
}

type Venue {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  events (
    date: String!
    venueId: ID!
    movieId: ID!
  ): EventConnection!
}

type Event implements Node {
  id: ID!
  venue: Venue!
  movie: Movie!
}
```

Where `*Connection` is a [cursor pagination](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) implementation detail.

In effect, I need to be able to write a query equivalent to:

```
query (
  $date: String!
  $coordinates: CoordinatesInput!
) {
  movies(
    date: $date
    coordinates: $coordinates
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        venues(
          date: $date
          coordinates: $coordinates
          # WARNING! made up syntax
          movieId: $parent.parent.movieId
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              events (
                date: $date
                # WARNING! made up syntax
                movieId: $parent.parent.parent.parent.movieId
                venueId: $parent.parent.venueId
              ) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    date
                    time
                    timestamp
                    url
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the spec of [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql) does not describe a way to reference a parent node in parameters.

---

**What works...** inverting the issue.

The inverse of the issue is simple. All I need is to get events defined by date and location and then retrieve the venue and movie associated with that event, e.g.

```
getEventsByDateAndLocation(date: "2017-05-18", location: [..]) {
  id
  venue {}
  movie {}
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it will increase the server response drastically, e.g. if we are display the 200~ events per page and `Movie`/ `Venue` size is 1kb, the response suddenly becomes 400kb (un-gziped). If the records were normalized, the response would be ~20kb. Thats a big difference.

A possible solution is to make two requests: one to retrieve list of events (along with the required identifiers) and one to retrieve the actual resources, e.g.

```
getEventsByDateAndLocation(date: "2017-05-18", location: [..]) {
  id
  venue {
    id
  }
  movie {
    id
  }
}
```

(followed by a batched-query to retrieve `Venue` and `Movie` by their ID).

This has the drawback of data composition complexity.

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious why the first `getEventsByDateAndLocation` query is so much larger (20kb normalized v. 1kb). That is definitely the right approach. The problem is likely to do with data loading/filters.